# Integrate Shiro with pac4j jax-rs implementation

Tags: java, security, shiro, java-security

I am using pac4j's [jsx-rs](https://github.com/pac4j/jax-rs-pac4j) implementation to enable only AUTHENTICATION for my application. For authorization, I want to use Shiro. But I am not sure how to integrate Shiro with pac4j.

Currently, I have a `Feature` which does the necessary JAX-RS Configuration and I have made it a `Provider`

The following are the features and providers that I have registered.

```
    featureContext
    .register(new JaxRsConfigProvider(config))
    .register(new Pac4JSecurityFeature())
    .register(new Pac4JValueFactoryProvider.Binder())
    .register(new ServletJaxRsContextFactoryProvider())
    .register(new Pac4JSecurityFilterFeature(false, null, "keycloakoidcclient", "callback", false))
```

I am using Shiro's `AuthorizationFilter` to do the authentication part. By this I mean I am creating a token based on the logged in user. I have registered this filter using Guice's `ServletModule`. But I am unable to get a hold of the logged in user. I am trying to inject Jersey's `SecurityContext` using `@Context`. But the filter ordering is messed up. The `AuthorizationFilter` gets invoked before authentication is complete. Hence the `SecurityContext` is always null.

Is there a better way to integrate Shiro with pac4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shiro provides its own `Feature` implementation to be used with `JAX-RS`. Adding that module dependency to the project does the trick.

And to get the user context from pac-4j, I implemented an `Authorizer` where I get the OIDC profile injected. I created a custom user profile and provided it to Shiro like this:

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new DemoToken(profile));
```

This way Shiro gets the user profile and then can carry on the authorization.